# mounting a davfs share always asks for credentials

Tags: mount, webdav, davfs2, tinycore

I installed davfs2 on my rPi running piCore-6.1. I added a line with the desired mountpoint to /etc/fstab:

```
https://url.../ /path.../ davfs _netdev,rw,user,uid=1000,gid=1000 0    0
```

I also created a /etc/davfs2/secrets (and called chmod 600 on it) with

```
https://url.../ user password
```

When I call `mount -a` I am asked to enter a username and password, as to my understanding davfs2 should check with the secrets file and use the specified user and password.

**TL;DR My davfs2 doesn´t want to use the secrets file I created...**

Answer (score 5):

After another 2 hours of searching I found the issue:

piCore does not store the secrets file in /etc/davfs2/secrets but rather in /usr/local/etc/davfs2/secrets.

Comment: Note that secrets for a normal user may go into `~/.davfs2/secrets`.